# Facebook login link works but not the login button, any ideas why?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create a php page where the user can login and then like my page. If I use the login_url in a  block, it works great.

However I'd like to use the official facebook login button, particularly because it allows the locale to be passed in, and then it will be localized to the right language.... and it looks nice!

Doing some research, it seems as though the login state in php is not in synch with the login state in js, but I have only seen bits and pieces of code (most of it with obsolete versions of the api).

Can anyone please point me in the right direction as to what I need to do here to make the facebook login button do the same thing as the $login_url?

Right now I observe the following behavior:

1. I open up the page and the Login button and link is visible because the php code thinks the user is not logged in
2. I click the Login Button and log in
3. The php code still thinks the user is not logged in, so it still shows the login button
4. Only until I click the Login *link* do I get logged in correctly and the login button disappears on reload.

Right now clicking the button just reloads the page and doesn't even ask the user to login. And if the user is logged in using the login-button, the php part of the page thinks the user is not logged in...

```
<?php 

require("facebook/facebook.php");

$locale = "en_US"; // TODO

$connect_facebook_url = "'//connect.facebook.net/" . $locale . "/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  "appId"  => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "secret" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "cookie" => true,
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 

// Get User ID
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id) 
{
  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try 
  {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

    $likes = $facebook->api(array( 
      'method' => 'fql.query',
      'query' => 'SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = "'
                 . $user_profile['id']
                 . '" AND page_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"', )); 

  } 
  catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
  {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} 
else 
{
  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

if(count($likes) > 0) 
{
  $likes_result = "User likes this page"; 
}
else 
{
  $likes_result = "User doesnt like this page";
}

if($login_url)
{
  $login_string = '<a href="' . $login_url . '">' . 'IDST_MENUITEM_SIGN_IN' . '</a>';
}

?>

<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) 
  {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 
    <?php echo $connect_facebook_url; ?>
    ;
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<body bgcolor="#000000">

<div align="center">
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>    
      <img src="http://www.myapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/MyApp-logo.png"/>
    </td>
    <td style="align:left; vertical-align:middle">
      <p style="font-family:segoe ui;color:white;font-size:40px;">MyApp</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>

<p>&nbsp<p>

<div align="center" style="font-family:segoe ui;color:white;font-size:20px;">
  <?php if ($login_string) : ?>
    <div class="fb-login-button" size="xlarge" data-width="200"></div>
  <?php else: ?>
    <div class="fb-like" 
         data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MyApp" 
         data-width="200" 
         data-colorscheme="dark" 
         data-show-faces="true" 
         data-send="true">
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <br>

  <p>
    <?php echo $likes_result; ?>
  </p>
  <p>
    <?php echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>'; ?>
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The PHP get evaluated only on the page load, whereas as far as I know the JS load asynchronously. This would explain why you have different login status between PHP and JS.

Comment: How would you recommend I fix it? Can I do any synchronization between php and js?

Comment: You should just use the Facebook Javascript SDK for the user to login. Afterwards sending an API Call to your PHP with his/her accesstoken and fetch userinfo.

Comment: I need to be able to run php code after I determine whether the user likes or does not like my page. Can I do that from javascript?

Comment: You could set the window.location to your desired PHP URL like this after the user logged in via JS SDK:

_window.location = "YOUR_PHP_URL"_

Comment: You could also implement all what you are currently doing in JS, so that PHP isn't necessary any more:

FB.api("/fql?q=YOUR_URLENCODED_FQL_QUERY", function(response) { YOUR_RESPONSE_HANDLING_HERE } );

Have a look at the Facebook Docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Comment: I need to execute php code to change records in my database. I suppose I could use your window.location approach to navigate to a different page that does the php stuff --- i'm assuming this will also work on mobile browsers, right?

Comment: Have you initialized the JS SDK at all? Don’t see that part anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There You Go.
Hope this helps

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      div#container_notlike, div#container_like {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
          channelUrl : 'http(s)://YOUR_APP_DOMAIN/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          var page_id = "YOUR_PAGE_ID";
          if (response && response.authResponse) {
            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
            FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                console.log("LIKE");
                $('#container_like').show();
              } else {
                console.log("NO LIKEY");
                $('#container_notlike').show();
              }
            });
          } else {
            FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response && response.authResponse) {
                var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
                FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
                  if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                    console.log("LIKE");
                    $('#container_like').show();
                  } else {
                    console.log("NO LIKEY");
                    $('#container_notlike').show();
                  }
                });
              } else {
                console.log("NO LIKEY");
                $('#container_notlike').show();
              }
            }, {scope: 'user_likes'});
          }
        });
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
      }(document));
    </script>

    <div id="container_notlike">
      YOU DON'T LIKE ME :(
    </div>

    <div id="container_like">
      YOU LIKE ME :)
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Replace the "YOUR_PAGE_ID" with your page id.

```
if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                        console.log("LIKE");
                        $('#container_like').show();
                        //window.location=YOURPHP.php
```

If you use window.location you will be redirected to YOURPHP.pho, if you dont want that

```
use ajax here in the code.

$.post("database.php",{userid: user_id, likes:1"},
  function(data,status){
  console.log(data);
console.log("LIKE");
  $('#container_like').show();
  posttofacebook(caption);
  document.getElementById("captionresult").innerHTML=data;
}); 
                      }
```

If you have any suggesstion queries or doubts on this.. Feel free to contact.

Comment: Thanks but this will be blocked by popup blockers, and I definitely need to execute php code (not just show a container). Any way to hook this in so that clicking the fb-like button will cause a non-popup login and then redirect to the like or not like php page?

Comment: If that's not possible with the like button directly... can this be done by using the offical fb-like button?

Comment: What official fb-like button does is when it is clicked the FB.Login() function defined in the above code is called. So it is okay to use any other custom button.. 
See the FB.login() Function in the above code. Just configure your button to call that function when clicked. Simple.. 

There wont be any popup Blockers.. I have used this code myself.
If you are afraid of it that much just switch to the ajax code I have given above.. Just go through it your answer is in it..:)
Happy Coding..:)

Comment: Actually an even better solution was to load the php page inside an iframe on the main page. That way the data was recorded into the db but the user wasn't navigated away!

Answer (score 1):

Try using session

```
if($user_id) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user_profile['id'];
    }
}
```

Then on your html page, you can add:

```
    <?php if(isSet($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
         Your html content here
    <?php } ?>
```

In case session not started, just add session_start() at the begging of page. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with a simple one line setting:

in FB.init you have no xbmfl default value set, so it's defaulting to false and thus not rendering any social icons. Simply add

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  "appId"  => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "secret" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "cookie" => true,
  "xbmfl" => true
));
```

According to the [facebook initialization documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.3):
XBMFL: Determines whether XFBML tags used by social plugins are parsed, and therefore whether the plugins are rendered or not. Defaults to false.